# How to start the JBoss 6.1.0 server from the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: java, jboss6.x, ubuntu-11.04

I am new to using Ubuntu and JBoss Application Server, I am not able to start the JBoss 6.1.0 server using Ubuntu11.04 terminal. The command I used to start is

`<JBOSS6.1.0 HOME>/bin$ ./run.sh`

When I used this command to run the server, an exception is thrown in the terminal as:

```
Failed to boot JBoss:
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name gnu/getopt      /MessagesBundle, locale en_US
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1539)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1278)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:805)
at gnu.getopt.LongOpt.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:529)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:196)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:816)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Please suggest how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

JBOSS should start normally with a clean install. Please ensure the following,

1. That you have correctly installed Java. (Run java -version)
2. That your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set. (Echo $JAVA_HOME)
3. That you have downloaded a legitamite JBOSS version (http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/6.1/jboss-as-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip)
4. That the permissions on your JBOSS folder are the correct for the user running the application (chmod -R u+rwx ~/my_jboss_folder).

You can then try various start options to further diagnose issues...

1. sh run.sh -b0.0.0.0 -c minimal
2. sh run.sh -b0.0.0.0
3. sh run.sh -b0.0.0.0 -c all